# How to specify the void return type for a constructor

Tags: php, oop, php-7, php-7.1, php-8

For consistency I'm specifying [return types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) since PHP 7.1, for all methods, including magic ones like [`__toString`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring), and even when the implicit return type is `void` like with [`__unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.unserialize):

```
class a {
  function __toString() : string {}
  function __unserialize ( array $data ) : void {}
  function __wakeup() : void {}
}
```

When I try the same for [constructors and destructors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), like this:

```
class a {
  function __construct() : void {}
  function __destruct() : void {}
  function __clone() : void {}
}
```

PHP yields `Fatal error`s:

```
Constructor a::__construct() cannot declare a return type
Destructor a::__destruct() cannot declare a return type
Clone method a::__clone() cannot declare a return type
```

The only thing I can do right now is to specify the implicit return type in a docblock like this:

```
/**
 * @return void (implicit)
 */
```

It puzzles me why, because other predefined methods *do* support an explicit return type. I couldn't find anything about this deviation in [the docs](https://www.php.net/), or in [the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type).

How can I specify the return type `void` for constructors and destructors? If it isn't possible in PHP 7, will it become possible in PHP 8 ?

Comment: constructors and destructors don't (and can't) return anything so why would they support it? It would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Constructors do not return anything explicitly. They do not have a return type.

Comment: A constructor returns the type of its class. This works since PHP 7.4 (or maybe 7.3).

Comment: Constructors return `void` as [per documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). After object creation, a constructor is called to initialize the object. My point is that you can't specify the return type `void` yourself, which is inconsistent with generic method declaration. Its like not being able to specify the `public` keyword on public methods because the are public by default, and your only options would be `protected` and `private`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It should be supported for the sake of syntax conciseness, as mentioned in this bugreport [bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75263](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75263) found by Swatantra Kumar. Think of it this way: why would the magic function `__construct()` be any different from `__unserialize()` ?

Comment: One difference is that `__construct()` and `__destruct()` are a part of the objects life cycle. The constructor automatically gets called when an object is created (if it has a constructor, it will be called). The same goes for the destructor (when the object gets destroyed). The magic method `__unserialize()` is only invoked upon some specific action. I see those as completely different types of methods, but I can see your point. I would rather say that `__unserialize()` should behave as the constructor, not the other way around.

Comment: It makes no sense that explicitly specifying the actual implicit return type of magic methods like `__clone()` yield **fatal** errors, while the PHP syntax is completely correct. Even when those methods are not always used, or specific to lifecycles. Isn't `__unserialize()` part of the lifecycle? It initializes the state of the object, much like `__construct()`. The documentation states the correct signature is: `__construct ([ mixed $args = "" [, $... ]] ) : void`, and when people follow that correct syntax, PHP terminates without any good reason. That could have been designed a lot better.

Answer (score 9):

The concept of *Constructors* and *Destructors* was [introduced](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) in PHP5. They do not return anything explicitly. They do not have any return type.

As the definition of Constructor goes, it is used in the creation of an object that is an instance of a class. It is used to initialize an object of the class as the constructor declaration looks just like a method declaration that has no return type.

Comment: This is another example of why I want to specify the return type of constructors and destructors, which is `void`. You can look it up in the documentation link you provided. People tend to think that a constructor returns a pointer to the instance, which isn't true.

Comment: @Code4R7 The signature says `void`, but It can not be explicitly declared. There was a bug reported for it 3 years ago as https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75263, which was marked by php team as "not a bug" mentioning "Constructors in object-oriented languages do not have return types."

Comment: Thanks for finding that bugreport. It's an inconsistency in the syntax of PHP, and it should be fixed. The report marks the design decision as "Not a bug", meaning that the folks creating PHP will not solve it for the foreseeable future, which is something we'll have to live with.

Comment: The constructor doesn't _"return the current instance of the class"_. The constructor doesn't return _anything_. Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/9YtX5). It's the key word `new` that creates the instance.

Comment: Indeed, and it would be nice if that could be expressed using valid PHP syntax, just like the documentation.

Comment: After all this time I still don't grasp the PHP concept of why `__construct()` wouldn't return anything. In the code demo it returns `NULL`, which is exactly the same return value that you get from a function that has the `void` return type. Furthermore, after creating an object, code execution has to continue at some point, after 'returning' from `__construct()`. The concept to 'never return' sounds like code execution will remain within `__construct()` for the rest of the execution lifecycle. Yet objects can be created and dropped at any point in code.

Comment: And I would like to say that any explanation will be too late for me. After 21 years of PHP I've gladly switched to Rust instead. PHP helped me to get this far, for which I'm grateful. And PHP still gets better over time. But I really can't stand unlogical quirks like this one which makes no sense at all and contradicts even the reference documentation, which as to date still explicitly states the signature: `__construct(mixed ...$values = ""): void`. It says VOID (!) So don't tell me that PHP does not return anything, because either you are wrong, or the docs are wrong.

Comment: @M.Eriksson if you actually put a return value in the constructor there, it does return something https://3v4l.org/di7As 

Comment: @GDmac - You're reading the comment out of context (since the answer has been updated since I wrote that comment). If you read the edit history of the answer, you can see that it said _"Implicitly, they return the current instance of the class"_, which is what I referred to.